# How to prove the Puiseux series converge analytically?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

In Reed and Simon's Analysis of operators, one of the exercises is to solve the following equation:
$$F(\beta, \lambda) = \sum_{m = 0}^n f_m(\beta)(\lambda -\lambda_0)^m = 0 $$
for $\lambda$ as a function of $\beta$ near $\beta_0$ where $F(\beta_0,\lambda_0) = 0$ and $\lambda_0$ is a simple root of $F(\beta_0, \lambda)$. The instructions say to try a formula like $\lambda(\beta) = \lambda_0 + \sum_{k\ge 1} \alpha_k (\beta - \beta_0)^6k$ and to "recursively substitute" into the above to find equations for the $\alpha_k$'s. Then, one must show that $|\alpha_k|\le CR^k$ for some $C$ and $R$. We may assume that the $f_m$'s are analytic near $\beta_0$ and since $\lambda_0$ is a simple root, we also have that $f_0(\beta_0)=0$ and $f_1(\beta_0)\neq 0$. The most promising approach I found was the following:

For brevity, write $z = \beta - \beta_0$, $w = \lambda - \lambda_0$, and $h_m(z) = -f_m(z+\beta_0)/f_1(z+\beta_0)$ for $m \neq 1$ and $h_1(z) = 0$ so that after some algebra the above equation becomes:
$$w = \sum_{m=0}^n h_m w^m \tag{1}$$
Now assume that an analytic function $w(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \alpha_k z^k$ satisfies (1) in a neighborhood of $0$. Define $w_j(z) = \sum_{k\ge j} \alpha_k z^k$ so that $w_j(z) = \alpha_j z^j + w_{j+1}(z)$, whence $w_j = \sum_{m=0}^n h_m w_j^m$ implies

\begin{align}
\alpha_j z^j + w_{j+1} &= \sum_{m=0}^n h_m(\alpha_j z^j + w_{j+1})^m =  \sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{i = 0}^ m \binom m i \alpha_j^{m- i}z^{j(m-i)}h_mw_{j+1}^i \\&= \sum_{m=0}^n \left(\sum_{i = m}^ n \binom i m \alpha_j^{i-m}z^{j(i-m)}h_i\right)w_{j+1}^m \tag{2}
\end{align}
Subtracting $\alpha_jz^j$ from both sides suggests we define $h_m^0 = h_m$ and 
$$h_m^{j+1} =  \sum_{i = m}^ n \binom i m \alpha_j^{i-m}z^{j(i-m)}h_i^j - [m=0]\alpha_jz^j$$
where $[P]$ equals 1 when $P$ is true and 0 otherwise. From (2) we get that $w_j = \sum_{m=0}^n h_m^j w_j^m$ implies $w_{j+1} = \sum_{m=0}^n h_m^{j+1} w_{j+1}^m$. To extract the coefficients, divide by $z^j$ and let $z\to 0$ to obtain:
\begin{align}
\alpha_j = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{w_j}{z^j} &=\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{h_0^j}{z^j} + \lim_{z \to 0}h_1^j \frac{w_j}{z^j}+ \sum_{m=2}^n \lim_{z \to 0}h_m^j w_j^{m-1}\frac{w_j}{z^j} \\ &= \lim_{z \to 0}\frac{h_0^j}{z^j} + \alpha_jh_1^j(0) + \sum_{m=2}^n h_m^j(0) w_j^{m-1}(0)\alpha_j
\end{align}
Since we get that $h_1^j(0)=h_1^{j-1}(0)$ from the definition, we apply $h_1^0(0) = 0$ to the above to obtain

\begin{align}
\alpha_j = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{h_0^j(z)}{z^j} &= \lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{i = 0}^ n \alpha_{j-1}^{i}z^{i(j-1)-j}h_i^{j-1} - \alpha_{j-1}z^{-1} \\ &=\lim_{z\to 0} z^{-j}h_0^{j-1}+\lim_{z\to 0} \alpha_{j-1}z^{-1}(h_1^{j-1}(z) - 1) + \lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{i =2}^ n \alpha_{j-1}^{i}z^{i(j-1)-j}h_i^{j-1}
\end{align}

My hope here was to throw away to sum term and try to bound the remaining two terms on the left via induction, but that does not work because I find myself trying to bound new terms that appear after substituting in for $h_0^{j-1}$. I think I am overcomplicating matters, but so far I have been unable to derive a useful identity for that $\alpha_j$'s that allows me to bound them using induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h_m $ be analytic functions around $0$ and consider the polynomial $$\sum_{n=0}^N h_n(w)z^n$$

Assume $h_N(0) \ne 0$ and that $\sum_{n=0}^N h_m(0)z^n$ has a simple root $a$.

That simple root varies continuously with the coefficients so there is a continuous function $Z(w)$ such that for $w\in \Bbb{C},|w|<r$ small enough $$\sum_{n=0}^N h_m(w)Z(w)^n=0, \qquad Z(0) = a$$

Then differentiating both sides we find for $|w|< R$ $$Z'(w) = \frac{-\sum_{n=0}^N h_m'(w) Z(w)^n}{\sum_{n=0}^N h_m(w) nZ(w)^{n-1}}$$
(the denominator doesn't vanish for $|w|< R$ small enough from the simple root assumption)

> Whence $Z$ is holomorphic and analytic $Z(w)= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty c_k w^k$ for $|w|<R$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, the continuity or differentiability of $Z(w)$ is not obvious to me. I know that Knopp proves a more general result in "A Theory of Functions" Part 2, but the problem is asking for estimates on the $\alpha_k$ ($c_k$ in your post) and I am not sure how to get them from "recursive substitution" as is hinted at in Reed and Simon.

Comment: "recursive substitution"  is good to solve it in formal series not in analytic functions. The continuity is obvious : if the roots of two monic polynomials aren't close then the coefficients of the polynomials aren't close (shift the root to $0$ and look at the constant coefficients). $Z'(w) = \frac{-\sum_{n=0}^N h_m'(w) Z(w)^n}{\sum_{n=0}^N h_m(w) nZ(w)^{n-1}}$ proves the differentiability : the RHS is well-defined and $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Z(w+t)-Z(w)}{t}$ converges to it

Comment: The estimate for the $c_k$ is given by the radius of convergence of the power series, $R$

Comment: Is there a way to get the decay $|c_k|=O(R^k)$ from the formulas that come out of recursive substitution?

Comment: $R$ is the modulus of the first zero of $h_N(w)$ or of the first zero of $\sum_{n=0}^N h_n(w)Z(w)^{n-1}$ you doubt it can't be easily found from the formal series. The analytic world is made exactly for that : simplifying complicated formal series problems

Comment: Your answer is admittedly way simpler and elegant, but suppose you were a masochist and wanted to find the decay from recursive substitution, how could you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution more in line with what I believe Reed and Simon were looking for:

Assume that an analytic function $w(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \alpha_k z^k$ satisfies (1) in a neighborhood of $0$. Express $h_m(z) = \sum_{k\ge 0} \beta_k^m z^k$ and plug this expression into $(1)$, expand, and match the coefficients of the $z^k$'s to get:
$$\alpha_k = \sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{|\gamma| = k} \prod_{i=1}^m \alpha_{\gamma_i} \beta_{\gamma_{m+1}}^m \tag{2}$$
Where $|\gamma| = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 +\cdots + \gamma_{m+1}$. Notice that no $\alpha_k$ appears in $(2)$ because that would imply some $\gamma_i = k$, so every other $\gamma_j=0$ for $j \neq i$, forcing multiplication by $\alpha_0=0$. This shows that $(2)$ works as a recursive definition for the $\alpha_k$'s and that every $\gamma_i \ge 1$.

Now pick $z$ in the intersection of the discs of convergence of each $h_m$ so that, for all $m$, absolute convergence gives:
$$C = \max_m \left\{\sum_{k\ge 0} |\beta_k^m| |z|^k\right\}< \infty$$
It follows that for any $r \ge 1/|z|$ we must have $|\beta_k^m|\le C r^k$.

Finally, define $K = \max\{C, 2n\}$, $A = \frac 1{2K}$ and $R = \max\{1, r, |\alpha_1|, |\alpha_2|\}/A$ so that $|\alpha_1|\le AR$, $|\alpha_2|\le AR^2$, and $q := r/R \le A\Rightarrow 2A - q \ge A \Rightarrow (1-q/2A)^{-1}\le 2$. For $k\ge 3$, apply the Triangle Ineq. and a strong induction hypothesis on $(2)$ to obtain:

\begin{align}
|\alpha_k| &\le \sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{|\gamma| = k} \prod_{i=1}^m |\alpha_{\gamma_i}| |\beta_{\gamma_{m+1}}^m| \le  \sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{|\gamma| = k} (AR)^{\gamma_1 + \cdots +\gamma_m} Cr^{\gamma_{m+1}} = C\sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{|\gamma| = k} (AR)^{k - \gamma_{m+1}} r^{\gamma_{m+1}} \\ & = CA^kR^k\sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{|\gamma| = k} (q/A)^{\gamma_{m+1}} = CA^kR^k\sum_{m=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^k \sum_{\gamma_1 + \cdots + \gamma_m = k - i}(q/A)^{i}
\end{align}
From the remark after $(2)$, we know that $\sum_{\gamma_1 + \cdots + \gamma_m = k - i}(q/A)^{i}$ contains $\binom{k-i-1}{m-1} \le 2^{k-i-1}$ terms. This, combined with the inequalities given after the definition of $K$, gives:

\begin{align}
|\alpha_k|&\le AR^k\left[C(2A)^{k-1}n \sum_{i=0}^k (q/2A)^{i}\right] \le AR^k\left[C(2A)^{k-1}n (1-q/2A)^{-1}\right] \\ &\le AR^k\left[2nK^{2-k}\right] \le AR^k\left[2n/K\right] \le AR^k
\end{align}